# Define a dynamic route prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a website that needs a city always in the URL. Something like this:

`http://www.examples.com/city/offers`

If the user try to access this URL:

`http://www.examples.com/offers`

I need to redirect him to the page to choose a city to see the offers. If the user already choose a city, I'm setting a cookie (or Session) to identify the city that he have chosen.

I can do it using Route prefixes, but how do I do dynamically?

I've tried this approach:

```
$city = Request::segment(1);

Route::group(array('prefix' => $city), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));

    /* Blog Resource */
    Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController', array('only' => array('index', 'show')));
});
```

The problem with this code is that if the user access this page:

```
`http://www.example.com/blog`
```

The system will think that 'blog' is the current city.

Another approach I've tried (the code is a little dirty):

```
$city = Request::segment(1);

if ($city == null)
{
    $city = Session::get('cidade');
}

if ($city != null)
{
    $city = City::where('slug', '=', $city)->first();
}

if (sizeof($city) > 0)
{
    Session::put('city', $city['slug']);

    $requestedPath = Request::path();

    if (!str_contains($requestedPath, $city['slug']))
    {
        return Redirect::to('/' . $city['slug'] . $requestedPath)->sendHeaders();
    }
}
else
{
    Redirect::to('/choose')->sendHeaders();
    exit();
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => $city), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));

    Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController', array('only' => array('index', 'show')));
});
```

The problem with the code above is the loop. If the user access the page `http://www.example.com/offers` the system would recognize that `offers` it is not a city and redirect the user to `http://www.example.com/choose` so the user can choose the city. But when redirect to `choose`, the system would recognize again that `choose` it is not a city and keep redirecting...

I know I have an option to use subdomains, but in this case I can't use because the client need this way.

I've already tried this package (https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router) but it does solve my problem 50%. The other problem is that it always compels me to put a city when creating URL:

```
{{ URL::action('HomeController@index', 'city' }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your post, I decided to recreate the situation, and bring in some custom route-binding.
Routes are read as 'first registered, first served', so you can keep in control like this:

routes.php

```
<?php
Route::bind('city', function($value, $route) {
    if($City = City::whereSlug($value)->first()) // find record on column 'slug'
    {
        return $City;
    }
    App::abort(404);
});

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@main');
Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController', array('only' => array('index', 'show')));
Route::get('offers', 'HomeController@offers');
Route::get('{city}', 'HomeController@city');
Route::get('{city}/offers', 'HomeController@cityOffers');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function main()
    {
        return __METHOD__;
    }

    public function offers()
    {
        return __METHOD__;
    }

    public function city(City $City)
    {
        return __METHOD__;
    }

    public function cityOffers(City $City)
    {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}
```

BlogController.php

```
<?php
class BlogController extends BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        return __METHOD__;
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}
```

Let's assume there is 1 City in your DB with the slug 'haarlem', the url with 'amsterdam' is just to illustrate the 404.

- localhost/laravel/public/ -> HomeController::main()
- localhost/laravel/public/blog/ -> BlogController::index()
- localhost/laravel/public/blog/show -> BlogController::show()
- localhost/laravel/public/offers -> HomeController::offers()
- localhost/laravel/public/amsterdam -> 404 not found exception
- localhost/laravel/public/haarlem -> HomeController::city($City)
- localhost/laravel/public/haarlem/offers -> HomeController::cityOffers($City)